# "for" loop inside a switch case doesn't work

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

I have a program that should theoretically in case of scelta1=1 open a certain function which re-assigns an array which is initialized at first. 
The problem is, the programs enters in the switch case, sees scelta1=1 but it doesn re-assign it just shows "Insert element [1][1] of array" "insert element [1][2] of array" without letting me insert them, while at first it did, so i'm going to assume the problem is not in the function.

**So summarizing : I would like to know why inside the case it doesn't loop and make me insert the new numbers for the array while the function is correct. Thank you**

This is the program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrici.h"
#define N 3

void leggi_matr(int MAT[N][N], int nRighe, int nColonne)  // The function 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
        for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++)
        {
            printf("\nInserisci l'elemento [%d][%d] da inserire nella matrice :  ", i+1,j+1);

            scanf("%d", & MAT[i][j]);
        }
}

 int A[N][N];
 int B[N][N];
 int C[N][N];

int main (){

    int nRighe = 3;
    int  nColonne = 3;
    int scelta = 1;
    char scelta1 = 0; 

    printf ("Inserimento matrice A\n\n");
    leggi_matr(A, nRighe, nColonne);

    printf ("\n\nInserimento matrice B\n\n");
    leggi_matr(B, nRighe, nColonne);



      switch (scelta) /* I know in this case it doesn't need a switch, i need it for                           
    {                  another thing */
           case 1:
                printf ("\n\nDo you want to insert array A or B?  "); 
                scanf ("%c", &scelta1);
                if (scelta1 == 'A')
                {
                    leggi_matr(A, nRighe, nColonne);
                }    
                else 
                {
                    leggi_matr(B, nRighe, nColonne);
                }

                break;

    }




printf("\n\n\n");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?  That is the first thing to do.

Comment: Since `scelta` is `0` when you reach `switch (scelta)`, you are not going to execute the `case 1:` code, are you?

Comment: your problem has for sure nothing to do with a "for" loop. please try to come up with a title that describes your problem well.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know, i've edited it. in facts it should have been a switch(scelta1) which should make me insert the A array. Sadly it doesn't....It just shows me "insert xx, insert xx, insert xx"

Comment: Is this a copy/past of the real code ?

Comment: `scanf` is a terrible way to get user input. Stop using it and your code will be better.

Comment: It's the part which is not working, the program itself is too long as being an array calculator. I just would like to know why the loop inside the case is not letting me insert the values.
@Paul Tomblin and OldProgrammer, i'm at basic programming i don't know really much about it still, so pardon me if i don't know how whether how to use a debugger or how to get user input without scanf.

Comment: @PaulTomblin, you have shared your knowledge that scanf is bad, but you didn't tell us how is it bad, what alternative do you suggest and why do you suggest that alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here-

```
  scanf ("%d", &scelta1);
  if (scelta1 == A)
```

`%d` is a specifier for integer.

Also as pointed correctly by Jonathan in comments, `scelta is 0` so when you reach `switch (scelta)`, you will not execute the `case 1: code`

You may like to change the value of

```
int scelta = 0;
```

to

```
int scelta = 1;
```

Also try to change the scanf to accept characters like this:-

```
scanf ("%c", &scelta1);
```

and then compare it like

```
if (scelta1 == 'A')
```

**EDIT:-**

Also it would be better to take `char scelta1` instead of `int scelta1` as you want to get a character literal in it.

Comment: This is another issue. Read Jonathan's comment

Comment: @haccks:- Yes I have read that. That is one which is pointed rightly. I tried to find the other!

Comment: difference between scelta and scelta1

Comment: @ryyker:- Thats the perfect example of chameleon question which keeps on changing! :)

Comment: Oh i see! That was the main problem thank you! But i can't understand something. Now it doesn't let me insert either A or B. It enters in the switch case, it has scelta =1 . It asks me whether i want to re-insert A or B but it doesn't let me choose, the programs ends directly after asking me.

Comment: The for loop is fine i think as i've used  this function to fill arrays multiple times.
Ps. What do you mean with character literal? like char scelta1 = a? putting a letter? it gives me an error don't know why

Comment: Ok, i don't know how and why but i solved adding a fflush(stdin). Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed:

```
int scelta = 0;

switch (scelta)
{
    case 1:
    ...
}
```

It isn't going to hit the case. The value is `0` and there is only a case for `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use good IDE like Net-beans. It shows most of these kind of problems.
Use this code snippet change.

```
scanf("%c", &scelta1);
if(scelta1 == 'A')
{

}
```

Not

```
  if (scelta1 == A)  
  {  //code 

  }
```

You are comparing an array pointer and integer.